# Can someone suggest optimized ways of color coding? I have given an example too

Tags: interaction-design

Color coding is what I thought but there are 10 different status. 
Example: Color coding: Different color indicating different status from 1pm- 2pm, 
another color indicating another status from 2pm-3pm.Since there are more than 10 entries for each main entity using color coding = 10 different colors could look cluttered.
User remembering so many different colors for each one of the status is not desirable.
Any suggestions on how can I address this design part?

Example can be like 
Cab booking initiated : Red;
Cabs Booked in the areas : Orange;
Cabs free slot in the surrounding areas :  yellow;
Cab booking confirmed : Green;
Source/pick up Address confirmed : Violet;
Reached source address: Brown;
Started from source address : Light blue;
Reached Destination address : Indigo Blue;
Booking completed : Gray;

These different status associated with time as well. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Color coding is about quickly identifying something. What information does the user really need to identify at a glimpse?

Comment: The user should be able to identify the status of the cabs in this case.Along with the time.

Comment: Relying on colour to convey information is a bad idea, because colour perception varies so much (different screens, lighting conditions, eyesight capabilities).  Using colour as an additional means to convey information is fine, though.   So my question for clarification/additional information is as follows: what primary means are you actually going to use to convey the information? Is the colour on rectangular blocks with text? Are the coloured objects on a grid where the row indicates the time?  Are the statuses of all the things to be colour coded simply time categories?

Comment: That's just too much data to show in one form at one time. I think you need to go back and rethink this at a broader level. Yes, color won't work here. You'll need to leverage other visual cues such as text, icons, layout, etc.

Comment: Alnitak,  Yes I plan to show in a rectangular blocks with the colors and status written on them. The row indicates the Cab driver name and the region.. Example: Person A(South).The columns indicate the time slots say 11-12 is one time slot.

Comment: I agree the data is too much, but reading the text and making icons would not work for user's benefit in case he/she wants to see all the basic information like person,time,status for each person. To simplify, I want to show on a rectangular block along with the time slot - status,person,exact location in that area..

Answer (score 2):

You have a sequence of status you need to present: Step 1, Step 2, Step 3, ...  If you labelled each status 1 - 10 it would be easier to remember than colours. *BUT* still too hard. So 10 items is too much.

What you need to do is devise a split in data you are displaying and the use combination of icon or text & colours.

e.g. Can use colours: (beware colour blindness - use different colour intensities) for Available / Booked / WithPassenger. And then use icon for the sub-state

Green

- Available : Booking Initiated
- Available : Cabs Booked
- Available : Cabs free
- Available : Booking completed

Orange

- Booked : No Address
- Booked : Address Confirmed
- Booked : At source address

Red

- WithPassenger : Started from source address
- WithPassenger : Reached Destination

Often text can be good option - quite foolproof and short enough.

Comment: This is a good approach of grouping of relevant status should be given a thought. But the substatus do not become intuitive to the user. Also as per my earlier comment, The requirement here is to show the status and the exact location together in rectangle block along with the time as horizontal axis and person(region) in vertical axis. In detail say on a click, this rectangle block will have client information too.

Comment: If you provide a sketch of your visual display constraints this will help visualise them.  But if your visual display constraints are very tight you may not be able to produce a reasonable UX.  A key item to understand is that the sub-status will always be more intuitive as 1 element in one of 3 contexts, than 1 item in list of 10.